# Почему параметр "radius" не работает при использовании getPlacePredictions google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Я пишу код, который делает запросы к автокомплиту гугла и выводит мне результаты на страницу. Я читал документацию, где написано, что можно ограничить радиус поиска при помощи параметров `location` и `radius`.

Однако, он никак не реагирует на значение параметра `radius`. Например, я выставляю `location` в Москве и `radius` равный 50 000 и пробую в значение инпута написать `Sara` в результате чего получаю города "Саранск" и "Саратов" в ответе. Которые находятся на расстоянии 650 000 метров.

Я читал [документацию](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompletionRequest), в которой написано, что `radius` допустимой значение объекта `getPlacePredictions`. Однако работает оно некорректно. Также я использовал `getQueryPredictions` и `getPredictions` и получал точно такой же ответ.

Пример моего кода: https://jsfiddle.net/bg479gna/33/

Сам код:

```
const autoComplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
const input = document.querySelector('#search');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
const getPlaceAutocomplete = (value) => {
  autoComplete.getPlacePredictions({
    input: value,
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(55.755826, 37.617300), //Moscow
    radius: 50000, //this value 50km. But i get cities on distance 650km. WHY?!?!
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'ru',
    },
  }, (data) => {
    data.forEach((item) => {
        result.innerHTML += `<li>${item.description}</li>`
    });
  });
};

input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    const value = input.value;

    getPlaceAutocomplete(value)
});
```

Как сделать, чтобы радиус учитывался?

Comment: Проблема в логике работы самой функции getPlacePredictions - вы получаете предсказание места. Для этой функции радиус лишь определяет порядок вывода результатов поиска места. Те если в радиус вашего поиска попадает часть результатов они будут самыми первыми. По моему для поиска места по радиусу есть другая функция. Попробую узнать точнее.

Comment: @coder675 благодарю за ответ. Как мне найти необходимый мне параметр? Потому что я уже замучался и все обрыл. И не могу найти именно тот параметр, который отвечает за вывод результатов только в определенной области

Comment: Поиск похоже нужно делать с помощью nearbySearch или radarSearch.

Comment: @coder675 но мне нужно .как раз предсказание запросов, а не сами места

Comment: Ну извините такого функционала нет. Видимо фильтровать по радиусу долго а предсказания должны быть быстрыми.